# admin url in email template

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, email, email-templates, admin-url

i am sending admin edit page url for custom module as bellow.

One point is that i am sending admin url from frontend.

[image]

My link is http://127.0.0.1/magento/admin/Cutommodule/edit/id/62/key/c269essasd78532efcbfd583797b53c1bcfbb/

But it redirects me to Deshboard.

Comment: Check the ACL of your module

Comment: It will redirect you to dashboard after login because Magento checks for key value and match with its stored key value. If not matched then it will redirect you to dashboard

Comment: If you are already logged-in in admin panel then this link will redirect you to dashboard but if you are not logged-in in admin panel then it will open that module

Comment: No this not works. not change if i am log in or not.